# Popup form window on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a popup window with absolute position inside an li.  I need it to stay visible when the mouse on the li or the popup itself.

```
    <ul>
         <li id="li1">hover menu
                <div class="popupMenu">
                    press here
                </div>  
       </li>
        <li id="li1">hover menu2
                <div class="popupMenu2">
                    press here2
                </div>
        </li>
  </ul>
```

simple example:https://jsfiddle.net/vntr8479/2/

Is there any solutions for this case? How can I make the window stay hover for the all process?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should surround the list in a div with absolute positioning and width and height set to 100% (so that when you move your mouse horizontally right, the box also disappears). Then, move your `mouseleaave` event to the div and make the fadeout code part of the `mouseleave` callback function.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#li1").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".popupMenu").fadeIn();
  });
  $("#container").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".popupMenu").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
.popupMenu {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
}
ul li {
  position: relative
}
.popupMenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="display:inline-block; position: absolute; height: 100%;">
  <ul>
    <li id="li1">hover menu
      <div class="popupMenu">press here</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$(function(){

    $("#li1").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".popupMenu").fadeIn();
    });

    $(".popupMenu").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".popupMenu").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

but this code will hide the popup only if you move cursor from it(popup).
If you want more advanced behaviour try adding other mouse event handlers.

Comment: what other mouse event handlers?can you give an example?

Comment: Regarding of what kind of behaviour you want to achieve, you may want to bind `$(".popupMenu").fadeOut();` to some other `mouseXXXX();`

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the `li`'s height on `mouseenter`, so it touches the popup menu:

```
$(function(){
  $('#li1')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $('.popupMenu').fadeIn();
      $(this).css('height', $('.popupMenu').offset().top);
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $('.popupMenu').fadeOut();
      $(this).css('height', '');
    })
});
```

**[Working Fiddle #1](https://jsfiddle.net/usf6p06g/)**

---

**Update**

I think this covers all cases:

```
$(function() {
  $('#li1')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $('.popupMenu').fadeIn();
    })
    .mouseleave(function(e) {
      var menu= $('.popupMenu');
      if(e.pageY < $(this).offset().top ||
         e.pageY > menu.offset().top + menu.outerHeight() ||
         e.pageX < menu.offset().left ||
         e.pageX > menu.offset().left + menu.outerWidth()
        ) {
        $('.popupMenu').fadeOut();
      }
    })
});
```

[**Working Fiddle #2**](https://jsfiddle.net/rzy442bj/)

Comment: this one is nice but has real bad effect on the Visibility of the site

Comment: I assume it pushes down content on `mouseenter`(?)  If so, I'll come up with a workaround.

Comment: I've added a new method.

Answer (score 0):

Change `position: absolute` to `position: relative` so the pop up adds height to the `li` element automatically.

```
.popupMenu{width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid black;position:relative;top:60px;}
ul li{position:relative}
.popupMenu{display:none;}
```